# Two buttons vertically misaligning, how to align them properly?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have two buttons, one an A element, another a BUTTON element. They both have the same classes (`class="button button--icon"`). While I'm applying the same CSS on both of them, using those classes, the buttons don't display the same way.

The difference between both elements is that the A elements are direct children of their containing LIs, but the BUTTON elements are wrapped in a FORM, which is contained in a LI.

The A button's vertical position is higher than that of the BUTTON button's.

These things I've tried, which didn't solve my problem:

- Hardcoding all font-sizes to 16px;
- Applying margins or paddings to the containing LIs and As, separately (this only moved my entire UL down)
- Applying an equal vertical margin to both the A and BUTTONs.
- Wrapping the A in a form as well (no effect, as I've no styling on FORM)
- `display: block !important;`
- `vertical-align: baseline;`
- Removing the box-sizing declarations

Does anyone hav an idea how I can move the A element down, so its top is on the same line as the BUTTON's top?

I've prepared a CodePen with a simplified version of the code, which shows what goes wrong. In case the CodePen goes missing, I've also listed the exact same code at the bottom of this question.
http://codepen.io/MHLut/pen/gpOREP?editors=110

The HTML:

```
<!-- Real world: this UL is normally in a table cell, not a DIV -->
<div class="example">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="button button--icon" href="#">
                <img class="icon" src="http://placehold.it/120x120">
            </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <form>
                <button class="button button--icon">
                    <img class="icon" src="http://placehold.it/120x120">
                </button>
            </form>
        </li>

        <li>
            <form>
                <button class="button button--icon">
                    <img class="icon" src="http://placehold.it/120x120">
                </button>
            </form>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The SCSS:

```
html {
    @include box-sizing(border-box);
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    @include box-sizing(inherit);
}

small {
    font-size: 0.75em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

button,
.button {
    border-radius: 0.125rem;
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 0.1em outset darken(#eee, 5%);
    color: #eee;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    padding: 0.5em 0.75em;
    &:hover, &:focus {}
    &:active {
        border-style: inset;
    }
}

.button {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.button--icon {
    @extend small;
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin-top: 0;
    .icon {
        display: block;
        height: 2em;
        width: 2em;
    }
}

.example {
    ul, form {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        padding-top: 0.25rem;
        padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
    }
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    li {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .button {
        @extend small;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `vertical-align: top;` to list items `<li>`s.

Comment: Since they(`.example li`) are display `inline-block` you need to set vertically align on them, so set it to top and the extra spacing you see on the other items is the padding from the form element

Comment: That was it! I knew it was something small and stupid. Moved the vertical padding declaration to `ul` only and added `li { vertical-align: top; }`. Works like a charm. Thanks :) Will accept in a few minutes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set these then they will align. Your list items are inline block items so you need to set vertical align top or else they will align to base-line. I set the forms to have no padding to show you the boxes aligning perfectly

```
.example {
    form {
        padding: 0; /* you original also have padding top and bottom on form */
    }
    li {
        display: inline-block; /* this you already have */
        vertical-align: top;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When setting up vertical alignment, I always find useful to work with `display: table`:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGEJKm

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: table;
}
li {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```